# Merge module is missed - Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm

Tags: visual-c++, wix

I'm creating distrib using Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset. And I want to add the Visual C++ Redistributable to the package. Here

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm

are words about merge modules necessary to make this. But there are no Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm in my
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\
:(((

I'm using MS VC++ 2010 Express. I have tried to Repair the installation. No relusts.

Any ideas?

Will be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

Express versions do not include the merge modules.

From the [product description](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express):

> Note: Visual C++ Express provides a subset of the functionality that is available in other Visual C++ editions. Therefore, some components, libraries, or features available in these editions are not available in this version of the product, even though they might be discussed in the documentation. For these features, you would have to upgrade to another version of Visual C++. For more information about these editions, see [Visual C++ Editions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx).

Comment: Can I obtain these modules somehow still using VS Express? Or it will be illegal?

Comment: It will be kind of illegal. But of course you can take them from a non-free VS installation. (If I remember correctly, VS Express does not support static linking of the libraries, non-free versions do support it.)